# Accessing a field from a model linked to another model with get_context_data()

Tags: python, django

I have the following models in my Django app:

- Model `User`

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField('username', max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField('Adresse mail', unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField('Prénom', max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField('Nom', max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
```

- Model `Company`

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    transporters = models.ManyToManyField(Transporter, blank=True)
```

- Model `Transporter`

```
class Transporter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

- Model `Supplement`

```
class Supplement(models.Model):
    transporter = models.ForeignKey(Transporter, on_delete=DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    header_row = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

Starting from the `user`, I would like to access the field `header_row` in `get_context_data()`. In my app, the user belongs to a company and the 'supplement' is attached to a `Company`.

Here's what I came with in `views.py` :

```
class UserSupplementView(TemplateView):

    model = User
    template_name = 'tool/try.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        context['supplements'] = user.company.supplement.header_row
        print(context['supplements'])
        return context
```

But it's not working and I have the following error message:

```
'Company' object has no attribute 'supplement'
```

But if I go with `context['supplements'] = user.company.supplement_set.all()` , I can actually retrieve part of the data.
Could you please help me to retrieve the `header_row` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `.all()` you then need to loop through the Queryset.  If you need to get the `header_row` field you would need to do loop through the results first.  You can do this in the view or in the template.

In the template:

```
{% for supplement in supplements %}
 {{ supplement.header_row }}
{% endfor %}
```

That should work in the template.

If you want to test to see if you're getting all the data, including the `header_row` without having to loop, use `.first()` instead of `.all()` in the view or `.first` in the template `{% for supplement in supplements.first %}`

This is based on you updating your query in the view to what you mentioned last `user.company.supplement_set.all()`

Comment: Perfect! It works like a charm. Thank you very much @ja408. I was trying to retrieve `header_row` at the wrong place.